# How to display values to the right of the bars that are not have enough space for label inside (bar chart)

Tags: apexcharts

For the user5 and further there is no space for labels on the bars (see the picture below). Is there any options to display such labels to the right of each bar (and in inverse color of course)?
[image]

Comment: is there a way to do this same think in vertical graph?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've partially found the answer. Data labels do displayed to the right of small bar but... This library is nice but always has "buts". Labels displayed with the same color, so they are invisible on white background, you can provide function to calculate color of each seria but... inside the function you do not know if the label would be over bar or outside it... so you cant guess do you need dark text for white bg or white color for dark bar bg...
I end up with semi transparent background and aligning label to the left. It's the less ugliest solution I've found.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with displaying all the data labels to the right of each bar, you can make use of [`plotOptions.bar.dataLabels.position`](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/plotoptions/bar/#position) property.

Even with the bar chart being horizontal, we'll still want to set the data label to sit on top.

```
plotOptions: {
  bar: {
    horizontal: true,
    dataLabels: {
      position: 'top',
    },
  },
},
```

To make sure that the labels are visible on the white background and nicely aligned to the end of each bar, we configure the color and offset in the [`dataLabels`](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/datalabels/) options.

```
dataLabels: {
  enabled: true,
  textAnchor: 'start',
  style: {
    colors: ['#000'],
  },
  offsetX: 20, // decide on a value which looks right to you
},
```

There are other examples of how you can tweak the data labels in the [documentation](https://apexcharts.com/docs/datalabels/).

Comment: Yes I thought about it but this approach requires additional space on the right side of the chart.